# weighted least squares inference in statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am wondering if the weighted least squares function in `statsmodels` makes a distinction between frequency and probability weights, as e.g. STATA? Is it using frequency or probability weights as defaults? In R, my understanding is that `lm()` interprets weights as probability weights.

Assume we have a data set with N observations: if there are duplicates, frequency weights would be used on the aggregated data set with M < N observations, where the frequency weight counts how often an observation occurs. The fact that M<N does not affect point estimation but inference through the small sample adjustment factor which might change from `(N-k)/(N-1)` to `(M-k)/(M-1)` if the aggregation is not taken into account.

A probability weight would instead denote the probability that a specific observation is drawn. The data set is not aggregated, inference does not need to be adjusted as `N=M`.

Comment: weights in statsmodels WLS are variance weights and not frequency/case weights. The underlying property of the model is heteroscedasticity.

Comment: GLM, which includes Gaussian, has both `var_weights` and `freq_weights`.